# How can I add comments to a custom page in Active Admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm using Active Admin in my Rails app and the default page for a resource has a comment field that seems very useful. I created a custom show page for my resource and now the comment section is gone. How can I add it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ActiveAdmin.register Project do
  show do
    attributes_table :name, :description
    active_admin_comments # Add this line for comment block
  end 
end
```

Use active_admin_comments inside your show block at the end. source [ActiveAdmin Source](https://github.com/gregbell/demo.activeadmin.info)